# How do I move to a line in ed without printing the line?

Tags: ed

In GNU ed, how do I move to a line without printing it? If I want to move to line 123, I would input `123` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but that would also print the contents of the line. Is there a way to not print when moving to a line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, you either want to move to a line and print it (which is the default action if no other command is given), or move to a line and perform some other command. It's a bit unusual to want to move to a line without continuing with some command... There is no "no-op" command in standard `ed`.

GNU `ed` introduces a non-standard command called `#`, which does nothing.

This means you could use the command `1;#` to move to the first line and then invoke the no-op command `#`.  You can't use `1#` as `#` does not take any address.  An address that looks like `n;` (for some line number `n`) is interpreted as "first go to line `n`" so that `4;/foo/` would mean the first line after line 4 that contains `foo`. Compare that with `4,/foo/` which is a range of several lines from line 4 to the first line matching `/foo/` relative to the current line.

Summary:
The command sequence `123;#` moves to line 123 and then does nothing in GNU `ed`.